# MigratorDotNet and Text Datatype on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, migratordotnet

I am using migratordotnet to sync my SQLServer 2008 database and need to create a column of type Text...

Am at a bit of a loss as to how to do this, as there is no System.Data.DbType.Text??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked it out with some trial and error...

DbType of AnsiString and a length of int.MaxValue does the trick

`Database.AddColumn("Notification", "Body", DbType.AnsiString, int.MaxValue);`